# How to align text vertically with tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I'm trying to vertically align the text for the following table using the tabularx environment.
Here is my code:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin {table}[ht]
\caption {General measurements} \label{tab:gen_mes} 
\begin{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |}
\hline
 Properties & Design A1 & Design B1 & Design C1 & Design D1 \\
\hline
Mechanical movement & yes & yes & yes & yes \\
\hline
Electrostatic movement & yes & yes & yes & yes \\
\hline
First movement $[V]$ & 6 & 24 & 6 & 24 \\
\hline
Hold voltage $[V]$ & 43 & too big & 42 & too big \\
\hline
Rotational stability & quite stable & bad & quite stable & bad \\
\hline
Lateral stability & very good & quite bad & very good & quite good \\
\hline
Maximum frequency [Hz] & 25 & no oscillation (get stuck) & 25 & no oscillation (get stuck) \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}     
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're setting the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`, there's no need for the `center` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `X` column type provided by the `tabularx` package is, basically, a glorified `p` column type. Cell contents in `p`-type columns are top-aligned. To get vertical centering instead of top-alignment, you need to run

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
```

This is explained in more detail on page 3 of the user guide of the `tabularx` package.

To typeset scientific units — such as volt and hertz — in typographically accepted ways, I recommend you load the `siunitx` package and write `\unit{\volt}` instead of `$V$`.

A separate comment: You may want to give some thought to making the table more "visually inviting" to your readers, so that they actually choose to stay a while and actively peruse the table's contents. This could be done by getting rid of all vertical rules and by employing far fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules. The second table below shows how this might be achieved in practice with the help of the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package. This second table also makes an effort to structure the header material a bit more systematically; the upshot of this effort is again an increase in ovderall readability.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % for 2nd table
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\addtolength\textheight{6cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional, for a less-cramped look

\caption{General measurements\strut} \label{tab:gen_mes} 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| Z | Y | Y | Y | Y |}
\hline
 Properties & Design A1 & Design B1 & Design C1 & Design D1 \\
\hline
Mechanical movement & yes & yes & yes & yes \\
\hline
Electrostatic movement & yes & yes & yes & yes \\
\hline
First movement [\unit{\volt}] & 6 & 24 & 6 & 24 \\
\hline
Hold voltage [\unit{\volt}] & 43 & too big & 42 & too big \\
\hline
Rotational stability & quite stable & bad & quite stable & bad \\
\hline
Lateral stability & very good & quite bad & very good & quite good \\
\hline
Maximum frequency [\unit{\hertz}] & 25 & no oscillation (get stuck) & 25 & no oscillation (get stuck) \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}     
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth{\mylen}{First movement} % desired width of first column
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Same table, but with a more open ``look''\strut} 
\label{tab:gen_mesyyy} 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} M{\mylen} YYYY @{}}
\toprule
Properties & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Design} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
\midrule
Mechanical movement & yes & yes & yes & yes \\
\addlinespace
Electrostatic movement & yes & yes & yes & yes \\
\addlinespace
First movement [\unit{\volt}] & 6 & 24 & 6 & 24 \\
\addlinespace
Hold voltage [\unit{\volt}] & 43 & too big & 42 & too big \\
\addlinespace
Rotational stability & quite stable & bad & quite stable & bad \\
\addlinespace
Lateral stability & very good & quite bad & very good & quite good \\
\addlinespace
Maximum frequency [\unit{\hertz}] & 25 & no oscillation (get stuck) & 25 & no oscillation (get stuck) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}     
\end{table}
\end{document}
```